# PHP: Using CURLOPT_POST, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, & CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST all three?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am setting a cURL method and the question I am running into is, if there are three options in cURL to set the request method, then how do I manage to account for each of these with each call? This seems like some serious overkill.

Do we need to be this redundant? See each case statement changing redundant options below:

```
switch ( $method ) {
    case 'POST':
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );    // HTTP POST method
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, false );
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, null );
        break;
    case 'GET':
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0 );    // HTTP GET method
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true );
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, null );
        break;
    default:
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0 );    // HTTP [custom] method
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true );
        curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method );
}
```

Comment: Unless you reuse the handle, setting the implied default values is a bit pointless anyway (`case 'GET'` is entirely redundant). A simple array map would do otherwise. Or any non-prodecural curl API even.

Comment: Can't you use just the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST with the method? Have you tried omitting the other two alltogether?

Comment: I am reusing the handle. Assume I am reusing the handle, tel me whether these other options are redundant & more information about how all three interact when the handle is being reused.